# Emulators' windows freezes on resizing or moving

Tags: windows-7, freeze, emulator

When I try to move or resize the window of Emulator (for Android, like [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) or SDK Native), it completely freezes for good. It is not a bug with the apps, because I used them on other computers and they are okay there.

I think something is wrong with my graphic card (or its settings). I have NVidia card [GeForce 550 Ti](http://www.nvidia.ru/object/product-geforce-gtx-550ti-ru.html) and the latest driver.
This problem occurs only with these emulators. I haven't seen anything like this in any other programs I use.

- I checked CPU usages after resizing/moving. It wasn't changed (I had 
  expected to find 100% core usage).
- I also tried to use [procmon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor), but there also were no critical
  issues. Just some crap network signals (all successful).
- Of course I tried to update Genymotion too.  Still no use.
- Moreover, I tried to run Oracle VirtualBox directly (Genymotion uses it internally). Its windows are resized and moved correctly without a froze.

Even if I say that I suspect the GPU, I haven't done anything to it (like changing its settings for particular app for boost or whatever).

Is there some **super-graphics-mode** which used only by Emulators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble was because of [AquaSnap](http://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap) (it is a windows manager). I've just updated to the latest version and all goes well now.

I thought about deleting this question because it was caused by some other utility, but I decided to write how I learn, which app causes the trouble.

---

First of all, I tried to run Windows in safe mode:

- Press win+R
- Type msconfig
- Choose 'loader' tab
- Check 'safe mode' with 'active directory' and reboot

Now, if problem doesn't occur anymore, then there is high chance it is caused by some software.

Run windows normaly and try to disable any apps relative to windows managment (for me, it was AquaSnap, Actual Multiple Monitors, Lightscreen).

If problem goes away, congrats, you find it. Now shut down every program one by one and you will find which one is a bad guy.